# regex last matches only

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex to capture:

```
 ( ( Workers  >  2 ) AND ( Minute  between 3 AND 10) )

( ( Workers  >  2 ) AND ( Minute  between 3 AND 10) ) AND ( ( Pais  = 32) AND ( Minute  >  5 ) )
```

i want to capture:

**Match 1:**

```
 Full match:    AND ( Minute  between 3 AND 10)

 Group 1: Minute  between 3 AND 10
```

**Match 2:**

```
 Full match:    AND ( Minute  >  5 )

 Group 1: Minute  >  5
```

I've create the following regex:

```
AND.*\(.*(Minute.*?)\)
```

but in the second string, the match start in the first occurrence. I need the last match.

You can check here:
https://regex101.com/r/6Nt3UX/2

Comment: Consider writing a parser to handle this task.

Comment: You'll want to backslash escape the parenthesis.

Comment: Use `.*(AND\s*\(\s*(Minute[^()]*)\))` with values in Group 1 and 2.

Comment: It's like @WiktorStribiżew comes up with these in his sleep. :)

Comment: @SunnyPatel You're assuming that Wiktor is actually a person, and not an AI bot created by Stack Overflow to answer regex questions :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And Gordon Linoff is the SQL bot.

Comment: At a minimum you need to use non-greedy quantifiers throughout, or be more specific about what you're skipping.

Comment: Tks all.
i'm new to regex.. 

( ( Workers  >  2 ) AND ( Minute  between 3 AND 10) ) AND ( ( Pais  = 32) AND ( Minute  >  5 ) )


i need to capture AND ( Minute  >  5  ) and not AND ( Minute  between 3 AND 10) ) AND ( ( Pais  = 32) AND ( Minute  >  5 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing dots to "not a bracket", and adding a look ahead to find only the last term, matches your targets:

```
AND[^(]*\([^(]*(Minute[^)]*?)\)(?=[ )]*$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/GLdrE7Pt9J6JGc).

Comment: Perfect. :)
Nearly got it for my first regex :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If You are using .net Then you can pass one more parameter to Match Function.
RegexOptions.RightToLeft  This will search for the match starting from right.
Regex.Match(input,"Pattern",RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
Thanks